# Need help on Separating Axis Theorem

Tags: c++, 2d, physics, collision

I am trying to check for collision between 2 rotated rectangles using SAT. However in certain angles, it doesn't work properly. (see here https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbetA.jpg)

Will help if anyone can point out my mistake. Here's my function:

```
bool SeperatingAxisThereom(std::vector<CVector2> rect1_points, std::vector<CVector2> rect2_points)
{
    CVector2 axis;
    float testMagnitude, min1, min2, max1, max2;
    int pointA, pointB;
    for ( int i = 0; i < rect1_points.size(); i++)
    {
        // Get an edge from rect1 and it's normal
        pointA = i;
        pointB = i+1;
        if (pointB >= rect1_points.size()) 
            pointB = 0;
        axis = rect1_points.at(pointA) - rect1_points.at(pointB);
        axis = axis.getPerpendicularVector();
        axis.normalizeVector3D();
        // Project rect 1
        min1 = max1 = axis.dotVector3D(rect1_points[0]);
        for ( int i = 1; i < rect1_points.size(); i++)
        {
            testMagnitude = axis.dotVector3D(rect1_points[i]);
            if (testMagnitude > max1) 
                max1 = testMagnitude;
            if (testMagnitude < min1)
                min1 = testMagnitude;
        }
        // Project rect 2
        min2 = max2 = axis.dotVector3D(rect2_points[0]);
        for ( int i = 1; i < rect2_points.size(); i++)
        {
            testMagnitude = axis.dotVector3D(rect2_points[i]);
            if (testMagnitude > max2)
                max2 = testMagnitude;
            if (testMagnitude < min2)
                min2 = testMagnitude;
        }
        // Check for intersection
        if (min1 < min2) 
        {
            if (max1 < min2 )
            {
                printf("\n");
                return false; // no collision
            }
        }
        else if(min2 < min1)
        {
            if(max2 < min1)
            {
                printf("\n");
                return false; // no collision
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not quite sure, but i think you have to calculate the axes according to the normal of BOTH shapes, not just the first one.

Taken from here: http://www.codezealot.org/archives/55

**"The axes you must test are the normals of each shape’s edges."**

And it seems like you are not returning true anywhere?

Comment: Thank you! Seems like I got my concept wrong, I thought I only had to check with the axes of 1 polygon. Works fine after I did this.

return SAT(rect1, rect2) && SAT(rect2, rect1);

Comment: Mind marking my answer as the correct one, so users can recreate what solved the problem?